# TimestampBehavior not woking for custom events in Cakephp4

Tags: events, timestamp, cakephp-4.x

I am struggling to figure out how to use `TimestampBehavior` with custom events.

In `OrdersTable` I have 2 fields `created_at` and `paid_at`.

My `OrderTable` dispatches the event `CommerceManager.Orders.afterPayment` after an order is paid :

```php
// in plugins/CommerceManager/src/Model/Table/OrdersTable.php
public function pay($id, $transactionId)
{
    $order = $this->findById($id)->firstOrFail();

    if ($order->status > 0) {
        return false;
    }

    $order->status = 1;
    if (!$this->save($order)) {
        return false;
    }

    $afterPaymentEvent = new Event('CommerceManager.Orders.afterPayment', $this, [
        'order' => $order
    ]);
    $this->getEventManager()->dispatch($afterPaymentEvent);

    return true;
}
```

I tried to add the `TimestampBehavior` like this :

```php
// in plugins/CommerceManager/src/Model/Table/OrdersTable.php

public function initialize(array $config): void
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp', [
        'events' => [
            'Model.beforeSave' => [
                'created_at' => 'new',
            ],
            'CommerceManager.Orders.afterPayment' => [
                'paid_at' => 'always'
            ]
        ]
    ]);
}
```

But the field `paid_at` stays on `null` after the status is set to `1` in database... and I don't understand why ?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything obviously wrong with the shown code. Consider that timestamping is only done on fields that are _not_ dirty, for fields that have a column type assigned, and lastly that the ORM will only save the field when it's present in the schema (ie make sure to clear the schema cache).

Comment: @ndm I just cleared the schema cache and set `paid_at` to `true` in `$_accessible` and the field `paid_at` still remains `null`...

Comment: Well, I don't really have any further suggestions, other than to debug the timestamp behavior code to figure what exactly is happening.

Comment: @ndm it seems it's because I save the order before dispatching `afterPayment` event in my code above. When I dispatch a `beforePayment` event just before saving it works

Comment: Apparently I'm effing blind ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯